# override spring-boot property in dependency jar file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I have a spring boot project that depends on one of the 3rd party SDK libraries which contains a YAML file with some google cloud URLs.

I want to override those values within my YAML, this works for most of my project but for some reason no luck with this perticular dependency lib.

**The Dependency Code**

```
@ConfigurationProperties("google")
public class GoogleProperties {
 String url;
..
..
}
```

Yaml file **application-google-prod.yaml**

```
google:
     url: some url.
```

Say this is in a jar called **google-client-sdk-1.0.0**

**My Code**

Yaml file **application-myapp-prod.yaml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: google-prod

google:
     url: OVERRIDE url.
```

So I am expecting that the OVERRIDE url should be used when the code in the lib is invoked, but instead it continues to use some url from jar file's yaml.

any pointers?

### **EDIT**

The  SDK contains another class
class with the following annotations in the SDK

```
       @Configuation
       @PropertySource({"classpath:application-google-prod.yaml})
```

I think this is forcing SDK to pick the value from the specific YAML ignoring overridden value in the YAML from my app.

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer:

A is have no mean reproducing your issue, this is just a suggestion.

---

Notice the absence of `@Configuration` on `GoogleProperties`.

You have to either add `@Configuration` on the properties class:
(impossible in this case) or add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(GoogleProperties.class)` on top of the class where you want to use the properties.

E.g: Your main class if you want to use them in all the app.

As mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-enabling), you can also use:
`@ConfigurationPropertiesScan({ "com.google.SDK", "org.acme.another" })` on top of your main class or any `@Configuration` class where you need those props.

**Note**: [As explained here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21358), the fact that as of spring-boot 2.2 we didn't need any more `@Configuration` or `@EnableConfigurationProperties` for the configuration properties feature is outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Philippe.
No luck with those options. But I think I might have found the issue.
there is another class with the following annotations in the SDK

           @Configuation
           @PropertySource({"classpath:application--google-prod.yaml})
I think this forcing SDK to pick the value from the specific YAML ignoring YAML from my app.